# Howto get page ancestors in WagtailAdminPageForm for unsaved page instances?

Tags: wagtail

I would like to get the ancestor pages of the current page in my [customized admin form](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#customising-generated-forms):

```py
# models.py
class TopicPage(Page):

    def get_topic_path(self):
        return (
            self
            .get_ancestors(inclusive=True)
            .filter(depth__gt=3)
            .values_list('title', flat=True)
        )

    base_form_class = TopicPageForm

# forms.py
class TopicPageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):

    def save(self, commit=True):
        page = super().save(commit=False)

        page.get_topic_path()

        if commit:
            page.save()
        return page
```

But with new `TopicPage` instances, [`get_ancestors`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.get_ancestors) do not return anything until the page is saved:

1. Add new `TopicPage` object
2. Publish this page: `get_ancestors` returns empty queryset
3. Publish this page again: `get_ancestors` returns the expected queryset

How can I get the ancestor pages of the current page in the `WagtailAdminPageForm` save() method, even for new (unsaved) pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `WagtailAdminPageForm` is instantiated by Wagtail's page add/edit views, it is passed the parent page; this is then available on the form object as `self.parent_page`. Wagtail uses this to validate the uniqueness of the page slug, but you can use it in your custom `save` method too - in this case, you could replicate `get_topic_path` by calling `.get_ancestors(inclusive=True)` on the parent page, and appending `page.title` to the result.